# How to Merge an image to exicitng Excel From C#

Tags: c#, excel, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

How to merge an image to Exciting Excel sheet cells, from c# i tried with following Code but it is not merge the image to cell it is floating in the excel sheet .

```
            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            //add some text 
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "http://csharp.net-informations.com";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1] = "Adding picture in Excel File";

            xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\\csharp-xl-picture.JPG", Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 50, 50, 300, 45); 


            xlWorkBook.SaveAs("csharp.net-informations.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a way to insert a picture directly into a cell. After a picture is inserted, the picture will move if cells above or cells to the left of the picture are added or deleted. Is what won’t happen is that the picture will not resize if the cell it is over changes size. If you set the shape’s placement value to `xlMoveAndSize` then if the cell’s column or row size is changed, the picture will resize accordingly. The picture will identify itself with the cell where the pictures top left corner is located as the picture may overlap several cells. Try adding the lines below to the added shape in the worksheet and see if this is the desired effect. I am guessing you would want to make sure the picture is contained (width, height) in a single cell when placed; otherwise the picture may overlap other cells.

```
xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\\csharp-xl-picture.JPG", Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 50, 50, 300, 45);
Excel.Shapes shapes = xlWorkSheet.Shapes;
Excel.Shape shape1 = shapes.Item(1);
shape1.Placement = XlPlacement.xlMoveAndSize;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i got it please up vote m question y u down vote it.